# How to increase the "workspace" in NetBeans 12?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can i extend the area where the code goes? I'm new with this IDE and didn't found the option to do that yet

[It seems that this line kinda limits the area of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al2AG.png)

Comment: To maximize the code editor you can use Shift+Esc when the code editor has the focus. To show only the editor try Ctrl+Shift+ENTER.

Comment: If you are referring to the vertical line in the screenshot, that is just a guide line, typically set to a line width of 80 characters, to help you see when any line reaches (or exceeds) that length. This can be ignored (just keep typing!), or even set to a different value (Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting > Right Margin). Also in the same location, you can set "Line Wrap" on and off.

Comment: Your screen shot is not showing that NetBeans _"kinda limits the area of the code"_, and if you want to put source code in that big blank area on the right there is nothing stopping you. Have you attempted that and found an issue, or are you just assuming that the vertical guide line will block you? Or am I completely misunderstanding your concern?

Comment: Yeah andrew, it was that vertical line that was bugging and confusing me at first, thanks for that advice, and also thanks david, that Ctrl+Shift+ENTER is something that will really come in handy, and skomisa, i was thinking, in the beggining, that the vertical line that was "limiting the area of my code", but there was another thing, every time i generated a automatic code, like a controller for a xml or a JFrame, the code generated was coming all bugged and missing information, i had to reinstall NetBeans to fix that.